# Removing trailing slash AND php/html extension. Trailing slash scenario fails to remove extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

/filename.php becomes /filename - Fail

/filename.php/ becomes /filename.php - Fail!

/filename/ becomes filename - success!

How would I remove the extension on the scenario that has the trailing slash?

```
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# remove php/html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html)[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.(?:php|html)(.*)$ $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: I don't see how `filename.php` would redirect to `filename` because your rule checks for `*index.(php|html)*`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Please be more specific, as your question says one thing, but your code says another.

Comment: The text is what I'm trying to accomplish.  The code was my attempt.  So far I think all that I've actually accomplished is the removal of the slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
# externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file and remove index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:html?|php)/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off with this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Trim trailing slash (only if request is not for a directory)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Trim .php/.html from request (exclude requests to /system/*)
# Ex: /page.php -> /page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+).(?:php|html)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```